# Transformar um vetor de char em um vetor de int em C

Tags: c, array, char, int

```
char ch[] = {'7', '3', '0', '8'};
int [] nums[2];

void transformInt(char [] c1) {
    int n1[2];
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {
        if (c1[j] != '0') {
            n1[j] = c1[j];
        } else break;    
        return n1;    
    }
}
```

Pessoal, preciso transformar um vetor de char em um vetor de int, mas não consigo. No caso,o '0' separaria os dois valores. Assim, n1[0] precisaria ser igual à 73 e n1[1] igual a 8. Tentei criar um método, mas ele não funciona nem para alocar o primeiro valor, não sei o que está errado.
Também não sei como faço para o método retornar um vetor.

Comment: O que vem a ser este array tam? Não seria o caso de você ir construindo um novo array até encontrar um caractere '0' e daí utilizar a função strtol de <stdlib.h> para converter a string em um inteiro?

Comment: No caso, a minha dificuldade é conseguir construir o novo array até encontrar o zero.

Comment: O array tam estava errado, era para ser o c1

Comment: seu código tem erros de sintaxe, nem compila...tire pelo menos os erros de sintaxe e tente executar o programa

Comment: editei a pergunta colocando espacços...use espaços para separar operadores (+, =, -, etc) e chaves ({}), senão fica muito difícil entender quando fica tudo grudado

Comment: int [] nums[2];   isso não é válido C

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `sscanf` é um método de fácil utilização e presente no `stdio.h`.

```
char myarray[5] = {'-', '1', '2', '3', '\0'};
int i;
sscanf(myarray, "%d", &i);
```

Também existem outras opções como o `atoi` e o `strtol`.

Referências:
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204471/convert-char-array-to-a-int-number-in-c/30414620)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420629/what-is-the-difference-between-sscanf-or-atoi-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer)

Answer (score 0):

Para passar uma array como parâmetro de uma função, teria que utilizar ponteiro, e pela complexidade do programa, acredito não ser o caso.
Ao invés de utilizar alguma função externa, eu faria a subtração do carácter por - '0'.
Quando se utiliza o '0' no seu código, é feita uma conversão para o valor representativo da tabela ASCII.
EX: '7' - '0' //Segundo a tabela ASCII seria igual a 55 - 48
E o resultado de 55-48 = 7
Como exemplo

```
int main()
{   
    char ch[] = {'7', '3', '0', '8'};
    int nums[]={0,0}, i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i<4;i++){
        nums[i/2]= (nums[i/2]* 10) + (ch[i]-'0');
        //printf("nums[%i]= %i\n",(i/2),nums[i/2]); descomente para ver como a variavel é preenchida
    }
    printf("nums[0]= %i\n nums[1]= %i\n",nums[0],nums[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Essa é uma tatica muito útil, principalmente para programas que serão enviados para o URI